# swift parsing JSON data

Tags: json, swift, parsing

so am trying to learn about JSON parsing, i want to extract some information from these fields..

```
        index = 90;
        property1 =             {
            href = "http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/supine-one-arm-overhead-throw";
            text = "Supine One-Arm Overhead Throw";
        };
        property2 =             {
            href = "http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder/lookup/filter/muscle/id/13/muscle/abdominals";
            text = Abdominals;
        };
        property3 =             (
                            {
                href = "http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/supine-one-arm-overhead-throw";
                src = "http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/exerciseImages/sequences/839/Male/m/839_1.jpg";
                text = "";
            },
```

i can get a chunk of data, the problem is when i try to sort this information out... here is my code

```
func parseDictionary(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    if let array: AnyObject = dictionary["results"] {
        for resultDict in array as![AnyObject] {
            if let resultDict = resultDict as? [String:AnyObject] {
                if let wrapperType = resultDict["wrapperType"] as? String {
                    if let kind = resultDict["kind"] as? String {
                        print("wrapperType: \(wrapperType), kind: \(kind)")
                    }
                }

            } else {
                print("expected a dictionary")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("expected results array")

    }
}
```

the error am getting is..

//Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x1014c8a60) to //'NSArray' (0x1014c8470).

Comment: The data is already "parsed", so your question has nothing to do with JSON -- it's purely about accessing the Objective-C/Swift objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your line:

```
for resultDict in array as![AnyObject] {
```

Needs to change to

```
for resultDict in array as![String: AnyObject] {
```

`[AnyObject]` is shorthand for `Array<AnyObject>`, whereas `[String: AnyObject]` is shorthand for `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`, which explains your error.